# Obj-C Text fields, float values and SIGBART

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am writing an iOS application for (among many features) calculating alcohol content from sugar before and after fermentation for homebrewers. Now the problem is; every time I run my app in the simulator, it crashes with "Thread 1: Signal SIGBART" once I enter the UIViewController with the text fields, labels and buttons used in this function (in the implementation):

```
- (IBAction)calcAlc:(id)sender {
double ogVal = [[oGtext text]floatValue];
double fgVal = [[fGtext text]floatValue];

double alcoContent = ((1.05*(ogVal-fgVal))/fgVal)/0.79;

NSString *theResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",alcoContent];

alcContent.text = theResult;

}
```

I'm really stuck here -- any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Enable breakpoints on Objective-C exceptions and turn on zombies in the scheme you're using.  Those steps will probably give you better information for debugging.

Comment: Go to the breakpoint navigator in XCode, click the '+' button, Add Exception Breakpoint, Exception All, Break On Throw. Now try to debug the program again.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if fgVal is ever `0`, since you are dividing by fgVal.

You will also want to use `doubleValue` instead of `floatValue`, since you are declaring them as `double`.

Comment: divide by zero is a good guess.  +1.  he must have tested with reasonable data in the text fields, so i'd also wager that the text field outlets aren't set, so text answers nil and floatValue answers 0.0.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I still don't get it working though -- even commenting out all the code and adding an "alcContent.text = @"Hello"" inside the function makes it go SIGBART.

Answer to the comment above:
I have this in my interface:
(at)property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *oGtext;
(at)property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fGtext;
(at)property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *alcContent;

And I am synthesizing them in the implementation.

Comment: that's interesting @HenrikHillestadLøvold.  The problem must be elsewhere.  Please take Daniel Martin's advice and add an exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try float in place of double.
Now put break points on each and every method and debug it to get the exact point where you application is getting crashed and then you will be able to find the solution.
Also be sure to connect each and every ib outlet and action in your storyboard or nib(whatever you are using).

Please notify if it works..:)

Comment: Hey, I've been debugging for a while now and it all boils down to this error, whatever I do (even when I comment out all the properties and methods in the header and implementation!):
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7482a30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key alcContent.'

Do you have any idea what this means? Thanks for your answer, @Ashu :)

Comment: I don't think that their is any key value pair or any thing like that which will crash your application try to find the exact point were app crashes..